# On User and Post Deletions Shouldn't There Be An Explanation Provided?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-users

I answered to a user to what appeared to be a legitimate question yesterday, only to find the user and the question deleted by the SO Admin today with no explanation.

Why is there no explanation provided?

Other deletes, modifications and similar operations offer an at least an optional explanation. Was the admin offered a textual reason box on this delete but choose to ignore it?

---

All that is shown is

`deleted by Martijn Pieters♦ 3 hours ago`

on

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351057/datagrid-with-different-binding-per-rows/46351538#46351538

Answer (score 12):

You'll notice that, for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351057/datagrid-with-different-binding-per-rows), the user who asked it is shown anonymized (user8651079, with a generic icon). That's an unmistakable sign that the user account has been removed from the site.

Yes, moderators do make detailed notes about why accounts are deleted, but that contains highly sensitive details that must be kept private. There is no way that these reasons can be displayed publicly, even to 10k+ users.

You just have to assume that moderators have a good reason for doing the things that we do.

Broadly speaking, there are a couple of very common reasons why user accounts are destroyed:

- They were nothing but a dirty ol' spammer!
- The account was part of a sockpuppetry ring, or otherwise being used to perpetuate vote fraud.
- The account was created to evade system-imposed restrictions, like a suspension or an automatic post ban.

If this clean-up effort ever removes a post that you *really* feel should have stuck around, you can flag it for moderator attention. Use the bottom-most reason, the one that allows you to type in an explanation of why the post adds value and why it should be undeleted. Be specific and detailed, as the dialog box advises.

For *posts*, when we delete those, we *usually* leave a comment underneath explaining our reasoning. Unless we think it's blindingly obvious why the post was causing harm to the site and merited deletion. Or unless we're busy and we forget. :-)

Comment: Each of your bullet points could be a generic reason to be provided and that is my point. Either say `Spam Account` or `Possible Fraudulent Account` or `User Issues Discovered` with `All posts and user deleted` would be fine....why isn't a generic reason provided?

Comment: Because there's nothing useful you can do with that information @OmegaMan.