# What can be the cause of a user deletion?

Tags: discussion, users, deleted-users

I've come across this question: [Angular 8: Create Facade Pattern for Subject-Observable design, Publish/Subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863648) which has been asked 3 days ago and has an active bounty since yesterday.

The user is greyed out and the bounty is being offered by the Community, which means the user has been deleted. The deletion probably comes from a moderator since the user was actively using Stack Overflow, and I'm wondering what can be the cause of such a drastic punishment? I thought user deletion was reserved to spammer bots, and things like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come the community user offers bounties?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291008/how-come-the-community-user-offers-bounties)

Comment: User deletion is never temporary. If someone gets suspended, they're set to 1 rep and lose all privileges, but their profile is still visible. Moderators very rarely delete users (only in case of account abuse, e.g. spam/troll accounts), but we can't see why an account got deleted or by whom.

Comment: I see you've substantially edited the question, but I wouldn't assume a mod deleted this user, and if one did, they probably can't say so and explain their actions since mods don't talk about why they suspended/deleted specific users unless they got approval for it from this user, thus this is not a very good question.

Comment: People also request account deletion themselves, there are almost weekly questions about it on meta.

Comment: @ErikA then the user would have deleted his own account right after having posted a question and offered a bounty on it? How strange is that? Why aren't we informed about what happened to an account? How do I know if the user stil needs an answer or not?

Comment: **"Why aren't we informed about what happened to an account?"** Because that's not our business. **"How do I know if the user stil needs an answer or not?"** It doesn't matter if OP still needs an answer or not, you're answering a question for the whole community, including future readers of the question, and not OP alone.

Comment: You can be sure the bounty won't be manually awarded, and that no answer will be accepted. If the bounty is your concern, you can only earn half the amount it it's auto-awarded.

Comment: Pretty visible in the wayback machine captures, this user did not earn the rep for that bounty the normal way.  They do destroy voting rings whole-sale.  The CM that handled this case should have canceled the bounty, be sure to flag the question.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant that's exactly what I wanted to know. Did you use something like archive.org to figure out?

Comment: @Twistingnether Hans mentioned the wayback machine, that's from archive.org.

Comment: The deleted account was a sock puppet that earned massive amounts of rep in a short period through suspicious voting to raise 4 bounties soon after. I agree that the bounties could have been cancelled before nuking the account.

Comment: @Nkosi indeed, it still draws attention on a potential unworthy question, and it still serves the poster (even if deleted)

Comment: @Twistingnether yes that it does. Mod flag it and explain the details.

Comment: If it was answered _after_ the bounty was posted, many times the bounty is preserved; since the answerer should not be punished because of the asker wrongdoings. It can still be answered, it can receive additional attention which can bring upvotes to whatever answers there are, and an answer can gain up to half a bounty. Which is not bad.

Comment: @yivi And yet the answerer could also be part of the voting ring and bounties are a way to "wash/clean" the reputation.

Comment: @Tom Since there was an account deleted, I'd wager it's pretty certain that possibility was investigated, and ruled out. In any case, it's not something that concerns me directly. I was just explaining why sometimes bounties are kept.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this particular case, the user account associated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863648/angular-8-create-facade-pattern-for-subject-observable-design-publish-subscrib) and the bounty was deleted because it was a suspension-evasion account.

The main account was suspended for vote fraud (i.e., creating sockpuppet accounts to artificially inflate their reputation). The user continues to create additional accounts as a means of both vote fraud and evading their suspension.

Moderators delete accounts that fundamentally break the rules.

I have also now canceled the bounty on that question. (As was noted in the comments, deletion of an account associated with a bounty will automatically transfer the owner of that bounty to the Community user, from which point things would otherwise proceed as normal. However, because the bounty was not raised in good faith, I've removed it altogether.)

See also:

- [On User and Post Deletions Shouldn't There Be An Explanation Provided?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356934/on-user-and-post-deletions-shouldnt-there-be-an-explanation-provided/356935#356935)
- [User before and now turns into a `user` and followed by number with an empty score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382467/user-before-and-now-turns-into-a-user-and-followed-by-number-with-an-empty-sco/382468#382468)

Comment: I think I had left the bounty in place as the *answerers* were posting in good faith. I wanted to give them a chance to at least earn half the bounty.

Comment: Only one answer, @Martijn, and I'm not sure it deserves a bounty... But fair point nevertheless.